# Enter arabic words in TextFailed. Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with TextField when I try to enter Arabic characters, or rather when I change the input direction from right to left.  The problem is that the cursor does not move in the entire widget.
please help

I try use TextAlignment.rtl class with textAlignment attribute.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Directionality` widget with `textDirection` property with `TextDirection.rtl`.

If you want apply in entire app you just add in MaterialApp start tree or root widget.

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  home: const Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: MyHomePage(),
  ),
)
```

You can also forcefully change if you want change for specific widget  just by wrap that widget externally wrap with Directionality.

```
const Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child:TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "اردو")),
)
```

For more details checkout this reference [link](https://logiak.medium.com/three-steps-to-right-to-left-directionality-in-flutter-934859ec083)